# remove autocomplete from cache results

Tags: php, javascript, caching, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've the following problem. I used to have an input with auto-completion, I removed this just recently from the field (as it was no longer necassery).

The field is now: `<input type="text" class="required text motivationname valid" maxlength="30" onblur="isDoubleMotivation(this.value);" value="" id="title" name="title">` nothing special right?

I've another auto-completion field which gets filled with information about cities.

```
var elements = $('input.auto_plaatsnaam');
    elements.each(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete( {
            dataType: "json",
            source: "/common/ajax/citysearch.php",
            minLength: 1,
            cache: false,
            delay: 100
        });
    });
```

The problem is as follows: some users get the auto-complete on the first (title) input field. I'm thinking it's a cache problem as removing the cache solves the problem. Can I force with php or js to flush the cache before the field is loaded? Removing all caches is not really beneficial to the site so I'm hoping I just could remove the caching of these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an update of a more recent version of jquery ui has solved the problem. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

A robust solution is to a add a parameter to your query url, containing the timestamp.

Example (not actually tested) :

```
var elements = $('input.auto_plaatsnaam');
elements.each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete( {
        dataType: "json",
        source: function() { return "/common/ajax/citysearch.php?t="+new Date().getTime()},
        minLength: 1,
        cache: false,
        delay: 100
    });
});
```

This way, the url for the  AJAX call is always different, so no cache is made by the browser.

Comment: This I know, It's more that I don't understand why the other field gets auto-completion why this is clearly disabled, the caching of the results is fine and not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you keep your js in file 'myjs.js' you can modify corresponding script tag to this

```
<script src="/path/to/myjs.js?version=0.01"></script>
```